# Dropdownlist in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I need to develop the blackberry application using jave (eclips), can you please help me what are the events for dropdown and how to read the value of dropdown list , i tried using  getText() method but its given error, can u please give small example on dropdown list in blackberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final String[] data = {"A", "B","C","D"};
        ObjectChoiceField ocf = new ObjectChoiceField("Set your status", data);
        ocf.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener(){
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                if(context != PROGRAMMATIC)
                Dialog.alert(data[ocf.getSelectedIndex()]);

            }

        });
```

Comment: but in blackberry 4.6 it shows only text.. it not looking like drop down list